# Multi-tenancy with a few twists

Tags: sql-server, database-design, architecture, multi-tenant

I have been tasked to extend an existing banking app to support multi-tenancy. The app currently serves ~100 companies with ~4000 users; and is ready for major growth.

The particulars are a bit complex, so here's a short history:
Originally, this portal was created for use by one mortgage company, who managed accounts of 3 types/roles:

1. Internal - mortgage Co. employees that can manage all users, banks, brokers & mortgage files
2. Client - bank employees that can manage just their users & mortgage files
3. Brokers - independent contractors can access just their mortgage files

Smooth sailing, then comes Client #2:
A separate instance was created for each new mortgage co. that adopted the system. The separate instances inevitably morphed into separate versions; which have now been migrated to a single, configurable version, but a separate instance still exists for each mortgage co.

1. The first twist is that an increasing number of brokers work for more than one of the mortgage co's, and are forced to maintain a separate login for Citi, GMAC, Chase & BoA for example.
2. The second twist is that bank employees have to maintain a login for each mortgage co's instance. (because of separate DBs)
3. The third twist is that more banks want an instance like the mortgage co's have, and require all the mortgage co's they work with to come to them (Partially driven by twist #2 above.)

There are actually banks assigning files to mortgage co's in 1 instance, then the mortgage co's employees are logging into the banks instance and double entering the data into their own instance. All on the same database server!

So we want/need to consolidate this N-squared bloat into 1 multi-tenant DB and eliminate duplicate accounts and duplicate data entry for our clients. Sometimes our client is the bank, sometimes it is the mortgage company. Its like a social network of banks & mortgage co's.

Questions:
 1. Is this a pretty standard MT implementation?
 2. Is it common to have shared objects in a MT solution? (ie. only one GMAC in the system)
 3. Is there a site out there we could use as a reference?
 4. Suggestions on whether to hide banks, brokers & mortgage co's from each other unless they had a relationship prior to MT? One option is to make it open: a directory where they could all network with new banks, brokers & mortgage co's -OR- make it closed, hide all entities, and require each entity to provide the GUID of another entity to discover & link to them.

Basic schema ideas I had for a MT beta:
 1. User table with every distinct user account from every instance
 2. Org table with every mortgage company & bank from every instance
 3. UserOrgLink table links Users to Orgs with roles
 4. RoleType table
 5. OrgID column in most tables

I welcome and value all input, ideas & criticism.

Comment: A few years ago I worked on a similar project and we found really helpful advice in a Microsoft white paper on multi-tenant architecture that we used as a guideline. I can't get my hands on it any more, but it looked a lot like this msdn page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx. We ended up implementing a shared DB, shared schema solution similar to what you described, which seemed to be working fine at the time I left the project.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, do NOT add OrgID to most tables. You are much better off keeping the Orgs completely separate (this way if you need to move a database to another server, or consolidate, you don't have to extract or merge one org's data). Use a control database that holds the mapping of users <-> mortgage/bank - they authenticate through the control database, then they pick which company they want to work with right now. The control database can tell the app where to find that company's database.

Comment: I had considered this but I thought this would mean all related queries would involve joining 2 bases. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: @bsod I'm not sure, not familiar enough with your schema and queries. I know you've written a lot above, but it's still too "big picture" to know if this is really a problem or not.